# Find all matches in a string without linebreaks

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string as followed:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img class="size-medium wp-image-427  alignnone" alt="" src="http://localhost/lucite/wp-content/uploads/Koala-300x225.jpg" width="300" height="225" /></a><a href="http://www.berg.nl"><img class="size-medium wp-image-426  alignnone" alt="" src="http://localhost/lucite/wp-content/uploads/Desert-300x225.jpg" width="300" height="225" /></a>
```

As you can see it consists of two images with a link. I want to select both the substrings starting at

```
<a
```

and ending at

```
/a>
```

so it includes the image.

My initial regex was this:

```
<a.+<img.+\/a>
```

This grabs the substring, but without a linebreak only sees one match instead of two.

For simple images i've found a more robust regex that finds both images even without the linebreak:

```
<[^<]+? \/>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to adapt this regex to also include the link tags. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, regex for something that doesn't match are a bit more tricky, try that:

```
preg_match_all(',<a(([^<]|<[^/]|</[^a]|</a[^>])+)</a>,', $a, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: I'm getting a Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier ']' when executing the script. It does work in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ though

Comment: weird... it works for me, are you trying the same exact code than me or did you modified it?

Comment: You're right. I copied it again and it works. Introduces new problems that makes me slam my head to a wall, but your answer solves the stated problem. Thanks.